# jQuery delegate function

Tags: jquery

Problem I'm having is displayed on this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/Sy2G4/

I'm using jQuery delegate() to create paragraphs that will respond to the same click event even though these new paragraphs were created after the document is. I know that delegate has been replaced by on(), but I don't think on() has that functionality. Anyways, i can't even get delegate to work the way I want. As you'll see in the fiddle, the new paragraphs aren't responsive to the click.

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('p').delegate(this, 'click', function(){
        $(this).after('<p>"No click me!"</p>');   
        });

    });​


<p>click me!</p>​
```

Comment: if you're using a modern jQuery, `delegate` is now `on`.  Also, don't use `this` in the delegate line like that, use 'body' or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').delegate('p', 'click', function(){
        $(this).after('<p>"No click me!"</p>');   
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery on does work with delegation.

```
$('.mywrapper').on('click', 'p', function(){
   $(this).after('<p>No, click me!</p>'); 
});​
```

HTML

```
<div class="mywrapper">
    <p>Click me!</p>
</div>​
```

You select the container element (something that will hang around) and tell it to trigger from the paragraph tag (current and future).

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/codyatfiny/pEbb3/)

Comment: I think you have your arg order messed up.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, `on` uses this order.

Comment: Nope, on reverses the order from delegate (why? I suspect because on handles regular events, live and delegate funtionality.). http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly delegating the click handler to `p`. Instead, your code should be more like:

```
$('body').delegate('p', 'click', function(){/*your click handler*/});
```

The difference is that now the listener is attached at `body`, with any click events that propagate up to it validated against `p` selector eligibility and only then executing the callback.

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy2G4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').delegate('p', 'click', function(){
        $(this).after('<p>"No click me!"</p>');   
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy2G4/3/).